# Why Travis fails to clone proper revision

Tags: travis-ci

my PR - https://travis-ci.org/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/builds/74302452 - continuously fails to build even though locally on 3 different machines it's working.

I receive very bizarre errors like compilation errors and tests failed.

The thing is that I've managed to build the branch - https://travis-ci.org/marcingrzejszczak/spring-cloud-zookeeper/builds/74301310 .

From what I see when Travis builds the PR it fails to take out proper revision. For example I bumped up Groovy to 2.4.4 but in logs you can see

```
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.4:testCompile (default) @ spring-cloud-zookeeper-core ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.3 to perform testCompile.
[INFO] Compiled 2 files.
```

whereas locally I have

```
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.4:testCompile (default) @ spring-cloud-zookeeper-core ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.4 to perform testCompile.
[INFO] Compiled 2 files.
```

Please help cause I can't merge a fully functional PR.

Comment: Have you tried doing `mvn dependency:tree` on local then add the command as a script execution in GMavenPlus so you can print the tree on Travis, then compare the results?  You can also try increasing Maven log level, it could be different profiles are activated that are affecting dependencies.

Comment: Yes I have - the dependencies are almost the same except for one difference. I have updated my local build to have the same dep and I've managed to build it without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues with caching AFAIR.